# fork() returns pid of existing process

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, fork, init

I'm trying to patch Android's init to allow unloading Android and loading Ubuntu on already initialized hardware. [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/100376233/Linux-shooteru/DAY1/init.patch) is the patch I'm trying.

But after kill -USR1 1 kernel goes panic and after reboot I'm seeing next in RAM console:

```
[   96.671325] init: Got SIGUSR1, trying to execve /system/xbin/ubuntu.sh
[   96.680786] init: fork done, pid=1
[   96.685089] [K] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
[   96.685150] [<c010ac50>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe0) from [<c0596408>] (panic+0x6c/0x198)
[   96.685150] [<c0596408>] (panic+0x6c/0x198) from [<c017e1d0>] (do_exit+0x98/0x650)
[   96.685180] [<c017e1d0>] (do_exit+0x98/0x650) from [<c017ea34>] (do_group_exit+0x84/0xc0)
[   96.685211] [<c017ea34>] (do_group_exit+0x84/0xc0) from [<c017ea80>] (__wake_up_parent+0x0/0x18)
[   96.685241] CPU1: stopping
[   96.685333] [<c010ac50>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe0) from [<c0109e2c>] (handle_IPI+0xd4/0x140)
[   96.685424] [<c0109e2c>] (handle_IPI+0xd4/0x140) from [<c01053cc>] (__irq_svc+0x4c/0xe4)
[   96.685516] [<c01053cc>] (__irq_svc+0x4c/0xe4) from [<c01058c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[   96.785858] subsystem-fatal-8x60: Q6 NMI was sent.
[   96.790924] [K] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
[  101.798248] [K] Going down for restart now
```

How can fork() return pid==1 (of child process) to parent process, init, which already have pid==1?

Thank You!

Comment: strerror isn't safe in a signal handler, I don't know what ERROR does and we can't see the scripts you call. This doesn't answer your question, but it's information that would be handy.

Comment: [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/100376233/Linux-shooteru/DAY1/ubuntu.sh) is script, but does it make sense, if init itself have problem? And thank You, I'm updated patch using strerror_r()

Comment: Thank You again, it's looks like all is now fine after updating patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strerror` isn't safe in a signal handler, so start there! :-)